# X is only available in IOS 9.0 o newer

Tags: flutter

During the development of the app with the plotter, it suddenly becomes impossible to build ios at all of a sudden. I will upload the related image below.

Other team members who do the same work have no problems.
Reinstallation of project ,xcode has already been attempted, and flutter clear , pod install has been attempted countless times. What can I do to fix this error?

Android builds normally.

I'm Korean and I'm not good at English, so I sent a question through a translator.

[image]

Comment: xcode version = 11.5
flutter version = 1.19.0

Comment: [✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.19.0-2.0.pre.143, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale ko-KR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
     Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set

```
platform:ios, '9.0'
```

in your Podfile which you can find in iOS directory.

What Xcode basically saying is that you need to point to iOS version 9.0 min.

Answer (score 0):

self answer...
firebase Cache error...

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

firebase Cache all delete ->